# while Form sumbitting extra blank item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

When I submit an answer form, the first item is getting the only empty string, how I can fix it and guide me.

Extra item picture:

[image]

**question model**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**answer model**

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
end
```

**answer controller**

```
 class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.create(params[:answer].permit(:body))
    redirect_to question_path(@question)
  end
  def destroy
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.find(params[:id])
    @answer.destroy
    redirect_to question_path(@question)
  end
end
```

**answer form**

```
    <%= form_for([@question,@question.answers.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m9">
          <%= f.text_area :body ,:id=>"ans_form" %>
          <label for="first_name"style="text-indent:15px;line-height:15px">Create Possible Answer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
          <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "col s12 btn waves-effect accent-4") do %>
            Create Answer
          <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**in my view (show page )**

```
<%= @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <%= answer.body %>
  <%= link_to 'delete',[answer.question, answer], method: :delete  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you expand your explanation and question a little please? I'm not quite clear on the problem and desired outcome...

Comment: In my answer voting app, I have a question, and the question has many possible answers, when I create possible answers I getting the first item is the empty string. Thank.

Comment: I'm not sure after my last (deleted) attempt didn't work - do you know the point at which the extra, empty answer is created (i.e. from playing around in the console)? Is there only ever _one_ blank answer?